# Why doe the sequence 16*[10,6,5,9] work for a bipolar stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor

I programmed a bipolar stepper motor (Step Angle: 1.8 degrees) connected to the computer via a velleman K8055 usb board and coding in MATLAB. I thought the sequence for full step drive was [12, 6, 3, 9], but it didn't work so I tired the sequence [10,6,5,9] which I found when I googled and it worked.

The site didn't give an explanation it jut gave me the sequence.

Comment: Please, add more information, like how did you "programmed a bipolar stepper motor" with Matlab? Which package did you use? What is your stepper motor? Are you using some kit or Arduino thingy? The more (clear, concise and useful) information the more likely people are to answer your question.

Comment: I used velleman K8055 usb board to connect the motor to MATLAB.

Comment: Edit your question and add the info to it, the board helps, but people will need to know which packages (functions) of Matlab you used (if you could post a minimal code with the important part that would be great).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10  1 0 1 0
6   0 1 1 0
5   0 1 0 1
9   1 0 0 1
```

if you motor is wireed A+ A- B+ B-  that will drive it perfectly
or to put it another way, swap the middle two columns and you'll see the staircase pattern

```
    1 1 0 0
    0 1 1 0
    0 0 1 1
    1 0 0 1
```

Comment: But why the *16 multiple tho?

Comment: that just repeats the sequence 16 times for 64 total steps